# How to convert JSON/string attributes to decimal number with precision and scale in ruby

Tags: ruby

Looking for some help in converting the json/string attribute to decimal with precision and scale (10,8) respectively using ruby decision table.

Example:

```
Input value:
Price : “000000045790000000”
```

Need to convert the above to

```
0000000457.90000000
```

Any suggestions would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show what have you tried. Also, there is no such _number_ as `0000000457.90000000`, it’s `457.9`. Do you want to get a string with trailing zeros?

Comment: Ruby doesn't have a built-in numeric class with fixed precision. For decimal values there's `Float` (not recommended for monetary values) and `BigDecimal`.

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by _"ruby decision table"_?

Answer (score 1):

Conversion: adjust the input to have the necessary amount of zeroes and put the dot at the desired position:

```
convert = ->(num, prec, scale) {
  num.rjust(prec + scale, '0').tap { |s| s[-scale...-scale] = '.' }
}
```

quick test:

```
%w[0045790000000 000000045790000000].all? do |input|
  '0000000457.90000000' == convert.(input, 10, 8)
end
#⇒ true
```

Whether you want to get a float out of it:

```
convert.('000000045790000000', 10, 8).to_f # or #to_d
#⇒ 457.9
```

Comment: You could also use `Rational` to scale the integer, i.e. `Rational(num, 10**scale)`

Comment: @Stefan yes, thanks, I thought about that, but than we’ll need to tackle with leading zeros anyway.

Comment: It might makes sense to separate the (internal) value and its (external) representation. Maybe in a small class with a parser and a formatter.